# How to deploy Django app not using Localhost

Tags: python, django, pycharm

We have created an app for a production facility that is very simple using django and python. But throughout prototyping we used Runserver command and localhost. The problem is this: We want to deploy the app without using localhost and the command line every time. The people using it wont be able to do this. It will be on implemented on one computer so it shouldnt be that challenging. The app pulls data from one database and stores data in another. It would be nice to have our own URL. Do we need to do it through wsgi? Apache? I know the problem is simple but there seem to be so many ways to deploy and many of them are overcomplicated for our needs.

Follow up question: I read that it just using Localhost isnt the best for this type of thing. Is this true?

Any help would be great

Comment: It sounds like you want to deploy the app live? If so, I

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to deploy the app live. So, I'd recommend using a dynamic hosting service like AWS/Azure/Firebase etc. If you want your own URL, purchase a domain, and in the configuration for the domain set up a CNAME file as well so you can redirect your domain to the live instance on the cloud.

Local host is better used for testing, and making changes without affecting the client and then you deploy/push to the cloud instance for production.

Comment: Our client wanted to keep it internal on a dedicated cpu due to data security. They basically told us not to use an outside cloud service. What would you do in this situation?